# Code to read from a text file and determine if word(s) are spelled correctly, but program gives up halfway through

Tags: java

For one of my assignments, I have to have been able to read from an .txt file and have the code check to see if the words are spelled correctly. Now, the problem is, I made it and it works. Partially.

For whatever reason, it decides to give up halfway through.
Example of what it shows:
https://imgur.com/a/XzIGY0b

Now, here is the code that I have:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Q5 {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        RandomAccessFile br = new RandomAccessFile("dictionary.txt", "r");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s;

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Enter word to spellcheck (or exit to end)");

            String key = input.nextLine();
            if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("exit"))
            {
                System.out.println("Ending program.....");
                System.exit(0);
            } else {
                boolean correct = false;

                while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (s.contains(key)) {
                        correct = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (correct) {
                    System.out.println(key + " is spelled correctly.");
                } else {
                    System.out.println(key + " is not spelled correctly.");
                }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm thinking it breaks somewhere around the boolean, but I can't be sure, I'm still fairly new to Java

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger?

Comment: The debugger gave me this error: Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: dictionary.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
 at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
 at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:345)
 at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:259)
 at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:214)
 at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:127)
 at Q5.main(Q5.java:7)

Comment: File was in the wrong place, but running the debugger shows no issues. It always stops at "test" and so forth, even when I tried typing in "world"